# How to avoid exceptions when creating a URL?

Tags: java, java-8

In a JUnit test package, I create a `java.net.URL` object and use it in a variety of assert statements. However, the constructor for the URL Object throws a MalformedURLException that must be caught. Since that must be caught, the constructor must then be wrapped in a try/catch, and that means you have to put the variable in scope outside of the try/catch.

Example code:

```
URL ocURL = null;
try {ocURL = new URL("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html");} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {}

assertEquals(variable, ocURL)
```

Admittedly, this is entirely aesthetic: I don't like all the extra code with no meaning littering my screen. Since I am passing the URL as a string, I know that it is going to be good, so that exception cannot be thrown (famous last words, though).

Is there a way to avoid declaring the URL object, then initializing it inside a try/catch? Is there a way to build a `java.net.URL` object without having to catch a (non-existent) exception?

Comment: You should at least log that exception as a good practice. I would personally wrap it into runime exception and rethrowe (as I usually assume that url is valid)

Comment: You could always declare the tests to throw a MalformedURLException. Alternatively, do you really *need* to use a java.net.URL? Could you use a java.net.URI instead (URI has a static `create` method which avoids throws)?

Comment: @sisyphus I suppose I could do `URI.create(string).toURL()`. It's got to be URL because of the assertion.

Comment: `URI.create(string).toURL()` doesn’t help, as it again requires you to handle `MalformedURLException`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a static factory method instead and handle the `try/catch` only once:

```
private static URL createURL(String path) {
     try {
         return ....;
     } catch(MalformedURLException e){
         // handle somehow
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
}
```